# How to copy data from a sheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba

The goal of this code is that it copies the data from workbook 2, 'master' sheet and pastes it into the 'key' sheet of workbook 1.

It ends up pasting the code into the correct sheet but also into the 'leads' sheet in workbook 1.

```vb
Sub Leads_Import_Key_Click()

Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("Workbook2.xlsx")
Set sht1 = wkb2.Sheets("Master")
Set sht2 = wkb1.Sheets("Key")

sht1.Range("A1:B10000").Copy
sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkb2.Close True

Worksheets("Leads").Select

MsgBox ("Successfully imported Key.")

Worksheets("Leads").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `sht2.Range("A1:B10000").Value = sht1.Range("A1:B10000").Value`.

Comment: U might be mistaking since you didn't turn on ScreenUpdating?

Comment: It should not paste in the `Worksheets("Leads")` Do you have any Worksheet change event code in the `Key` Sheet?

Comment: @BigBen this fixed it - can you write it as an answer so I mark it as correct? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use the clipboard, just do a straight value transfer:

```
sht2.Range("A1:B10000").Value = sht1.Range("A1:B10000").Value
```